# Import my Path variable from Windows to Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, bash

Ive just installed BUW and now I want to get all my path folders from windows to BUW. Any way to do this? I've searcherd here and googled but have no luck for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to get all my path folders from windows to BUW

I decided it was easier to build the path myself in Cygwin because:

- I get full control over what is in the path (if I install Windows programs that mess with the path they don't mess up my `bash` path).
- My bash path is shorted (I don't need everything in the Windows path transferred to `bash`).
- No need for path conversions from  `\` to `/` and `;` to `:` (which is tricky to get right).

A similar approach should work for BUW.

I added the following code to `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
# Build up the path using the directories in ~/.path_elements
unset PATH
while read line; do 
  PATH="${PATH}$line"; 
done < ~/.path_elements
```

...

```
# Optional: Add current directory to path
export PATH=".:${PATH}"
```

And the following to `~/.path_elements`:

```
/home/DavidPostill/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/c/Windows/system32:
/c/Windows
```

Customise as appropriate.